# Как опустить scroll до низу?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

делаю по примеру, но выскакивает ошибка:

```
ReferenceError: scrollChat is not defined
```

Код:

```
 function scrollChat() {
    var allMessChat = document.getElementsByClassName('all-mess-chat')[0];
    allMessChat.scrollTop = allMessChat.scrollHeight;
}
```

Comment: Опечатка скорее всего, вы скопировали код или заново написали для вопроса? Поищите где у вас есть `scrollChat`

Comment: да опечатка, scrollChat это функция

Comment: Проблема не в приведенном куске кода. Место, откуда вы вызываете эту функцию, её не видит. Вероятно она либо создается позднее, либо в другой области видимости

Comment: функцию поставил в конце кода, ошибка пропала..но скрол не опускается до низу

Comment: @МаксимКоханський добавьте и выполните код `console.log(allMessChat)`. Что отображается в консоле?

Comment: scrollHeight: 1708
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 2046

Comment: @Alex, там много скинул только scroll

Answer (score 1):

Очень легко

```
    $('.down').on('click', function(e){
        var documentHeight = $(document).outerHeight();
        var widowHeight = $(window).height();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: documentHeight - widowHeight}, 'slow');
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```